# What level are these Griffens?

Tags: castle-clash

I was playing Here Be Monsters, and I came across son unusual Griffen's, my Griffens are lvl 5 and on the right while the weird unknown level ones are on the left, basically I want to know what level they are because they are far better than mine.

[image: Screenshot From In-Game]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Griffins with brown armor are level 1 or 2, and should not be stronger than your level 5 Griffins.

Here's a table from http://castle-clash.wikia.com/wiki/Griffin showing the appearances and statistics of each level of Griffin.

[image]

Comment: They look the same, but these ones had metal like helmets on.